# Embedding instagram webpage inside an iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, instagram

I am getting this error:

```
Refused to display 'http://instagram.com/p/page/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.
```

I want to show instagram page inside my web because it is a mobile app and I want to use my back buttons.

This is my webpage:

```
<body id="responsiveDemo">  
<div data-role="page" id="test" data-theme="g">
<div data-theme="g" data-role="header">
    <a href="javascript:history.back()" data-icon="back" data-iconpos="notext"></a>
    <h1>Instagram</h1>
</div>

<div data-role="content">

<iframe id="iframeInstagram" src="" name="IframeInstagram" style="width: 100%; height: 1000px; border: medium none;visibility: visible;"></iframe>

            <script>

            var query = location.search.substring(1);
            //console.log(query);
            var parameters = {};
            var keyValues = query.split(/&/);
            for (var i = 0; i < keyValues.length;i++) {
                var keyValuePairs = keyValues[i].split(/==/);
                var key = keyValuePairs[0];
                var value = keyValuePairs[1];
                parameters[key] = value;
            }



                /*+$(document).ready(function() {
                    //console.log(parameters['page']);
                    document.getElementById('iframeColaborador').src = parameters['colaborador'];


                });
                */
                //$(document).on("pageload", '#test', function() {
                $(document).on("pageshow", '#test', function() {
                //$(document).load(function() {
                    console.log(parameters['instagram']);
                    document.getElementById('iframeInstagram').src = parameters['instagram'];
                    //document.getElementById('iframeNews').src = 'http://www.unican.es';


                });


            </script>



</div> <!-- /content -->
```

I was using this webpage to show others webs but I don't know why it fails with instagram.

Comment: you cant do this clientside, you could fetch the page serverside .. or  do some dirty yql-hack

Answer (score 44, accepted):

YES, you can display instagram pages with this format

```
https://www.instagram.com/p/BdJRABkDbXU/
```

...inside iframes as long as you add the suffix `embed/` like

```
<iframe width="320" height="440" src="https://www.instagram.com/p/BdJRABkDbXU/embed/" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/51mankb8/)**

Comment: Can you show the votes page instead of the photo? I would want to be able to upvote or downvote or so. I cannot show that page

Comment: Your answer embed the photo and number of likes from instagram but I need to embed the like button to be able to uplike a photo. Is that possible? With your code, I have to press on "instagram" view on instagram to vote or leave a comment. I would want to do that inside my app

Comment: @Biribu I don't think it's possible inside the iframe with the current API, you would need to view the photo (and to login) in Instagram to be able to like it or leave a comment.

Comment: ok, thanks. Well, I should think in other way to do it. I am ok with this behaviour on android but on ios I cannot go back to my app. And I can't open safari with instagram link I don't know why. Thanks for your time

Comment: To use the latest embed style, you should add `/?cr=1&v=7` at the end of the `src`, so you would have: `<iframe width="320" height="440" src="http://instagram.com/p/qbq6fIJMVZ/embed/?cr=1&v=7" frameborder="0"></iframe>`

Comment: is there any way to show entire instagram page in to our website for example "https://www.instagram.com/jaybhalodi/" i want this entire page to load in my website, i got same error Refused to display 'https://www.instagram.com/jaybhalodi/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.

Comment: This solution did not work for me unless i've added https (s for secure!).

Comment: Other options you can add to the iframe: scrolling="no" allowtransparency="true"

Answer (score 5):

You won't be able to because Instagram denies external websites from putting their website in a frame. This is why you got that error message about `X-Frame-Options` being set to `SAMEORIGIN` -- same origin means it will only allow Instagram to use the frame, but not others.

Comment: Ok thanks. Then I should check how to open a browser outside the webapp browser in javascript. Damm it, it seems too easy!

Comment: Yes, it's possible. See my answer.

Answer (score 5):

First of all Instagram let you embed the shares you did. All you have to do is

```
 
1-open instagram from your web browser
2-click any share you have 
3-at right bottom there is hidden menu with shape of ... (3 dot) click it 
4-select second menu which is embed to website
5-click copy link from the next page  and use that code to use instagram embeded link at your page
```

also if you find it difficult or you want the pure code here is all you have to do use below code with your own url

```
<blockquote class="instagram-media" data-instgrm-version="7" >
<a href="https://www.instagram.com/p/BT8cmZRlkVJ/"></a> 
</blockquote>
<script async defer src="//platform.instagram.com/en_US/embeds.js"></script>
```