# Is possible to open instagram in iframe without API

Tags: javascript, html, css

another way to open instagram in iframe tag without having API

Comment: This should help you embed instagram, [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24739663/embebing-instagram-webpage-inside-an-iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24739663/embebing-instagram-webpage-inside-an-iframe)!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Embebing instagram webpage inside an iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24739663/embebing-instagram-webpage-inside-an-iframe)

Answer (score 0):

You can always check any url(`example.com`) is allowed in IFrame or not for a specific `Origin` by following method:

```
function isAllowededByXFrameOption({ header, origin }) {
  if (header["X-Frame-Options".toLowerCase()]) {
    let options = header["X-Frame-Options".toLowerCase()].toLowerCase();
    if (options === "SAMEORIGIN".toLowerCase()) {
      return false;
    } else if (options === "DENY".toLowerCase()) {
      return false;
    } else if (~options.indexOf("ALLOW-FROM".toLowerCase())) {
      let allowedOrigins = options.split(" ").slice(1);
      return allowedOrigins.find(
        _o => url.parse(_o).host === url.parse(origin).host
      );
    }
  }
  if (header["Content-Security-Policy".toLowerCase()]) {
    let _options = header["Content-Security-Policy".toLowerCase()];
    let CheckOriginInSource = source_name => {
      _options = _options.split(";");
      _options = _options.find(_o => _o.indexOf(source_name) > -1);
      _options = _options.split(" ").slice(1);
      return _options.find(_o => url.parse(_o).host === url.parse(origin).host);
    };
    if (_options.indexOf("frame-src") > -1) {
      return CheckOriginInSource("frame-src");
    } else if (_options.indexOf("child-src")) {
      return CheckOriginInSource("child-src");
    } else if (_options.indexOf("default-src")) {
      return CheckOriginInSource("default-src");
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}
const got = require("got");
const metascraper = require("metascraper")([
  require("metascraper-author")(),
  require("metascraper-date")(),
  require("metascraper-description")(),
  require("metascraper-image")(),
  require("metascraper-logo")(),
  require("metascraper-clearbit-logo")(),
  require("metascraper-publisher")(),
  require("metascraper-title")(),
  require("metascraper-url")()
]);
const Domain = "example.com";
(async () => {
     const { body: html, url, headers } = await got(Domain);
     const metadata = await metascraper({ html, url });
     const isAllowed = isAllowededByXFrameOption({
                        header: headers,
                        origin: "www.app4pc.com"
                    })
})();
```